# Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget'

Tags: javascript, html

**tengo un problema a resolver:** 
contar la cantidad de cada caracter de una palabra (input text)
**y tengo este error:**
Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': parameter 2 is not of type 'Object'

me podrian decir cual es el error y por que?

```
function contarCaracteres() {
  
  let str = document.getElementById('palabra').value; //value del input text

  str = str.replace(/\s/g, "");

  final = {} //Donde guardamos los resultados

  for(let char in str){                         //indice de cada caracter
      if(str[char] in final) {                   //Si ya existe, simplemente aumentamos el contador
        final[str[char]] = final[str[char]] + 1
      } else {                                  // Si no existe, lo inicializamos a 1
        final[str[char]] = 1
    }
  }
  //Mostar los resultados
  tmp = ``
  Object.keys(final).forEach(function(letra){
    tmp += `La cantidad de ${letra} es: ${final[letra]} \n`
  })
  return tmp
  
}

document.querySelector("#boton1").addEventListener("click",contarCaracteres());
```

Comment: `contarCaracteres()` esta devolviendo el valor de `tmp` el cual es un `string`, es lo mismo que `addEventListener("click","texto devuelto de ejemplo")`, te recomiendo que no devuelvas nada y trabajes todos los cambios de `#boton1` dentro de la propia función

Comment: Sería `.addEventListener("click",contarCaracteres)` la función es un argumento, no la invocas tú sino que la invocará el evento más adelante

Comment: Solo agrego como curiosidad que `addEventListener` solo verifica que se envíe un objeto, cualquiera sea. `{}` no lanza error, aunque obviamente no hace nada.

Answer (score 1):

El método addEventListener(nombre_evento, objeto) tiene como primer argumento un evento, tu has usado **click**. Y el segundo es un objeto: el nombre de la función que va a ser invocada por ese evento.
Tu usas una llamada a una función, o sea, que al invocar a **addEventListener** se ejecuta esa función y devuelve una cadena (string), no un objeto.
Creo que la solución es
document.querySelector("#boton1").addEventListener("click",contarCaracteres)
Al pulsar el botón se ejecutará la función contarCaracteres.
Prueba esta solución

```js
function contarCaracteres() {
  let str = "alue del input text";
  str = str.replace(/\s/g, "");
  final = {} //Donde guardamos los resultados
  for(let char in str){          //indice de cada caracter
      if(str[char] in final) {   //Si ya existe, simplemente aumentamos el contador
        final[str[char]] = final[str[char]] + 1
      } else {                   // Si no existe, lo inicializamos a 1
        final[str[char]] = 1
    }
  }
  //Mostar los resultados
  tmp = ``
  Object.keys(final).forEach(function(letra){
    tmp += `La cantidad de ${letra} es: ${final[letra]} \n`
  })
  console.log(tmp)
}
document.querySelector("#boton1").addEventListener("click",contarCaracteres);
```

Así verás el resultado en consola. Si quieres tenerlo en una pa´gina web, puedes insertar el resultado en un bloque div, con la propiedad innerText por ejemplo.